# How to implement Swing JTable pagination?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have been developing an application that requires me to implement pagination in `JTable`. I populate the `JTable` with the data in MySQL database. All this works perfectly.

I really don't know how to implement the concept of pagination in my `JTable`. I am held up with this problem for over a week now and I just can't understand how to get it done. I have over 500 records in my database, and I want to show 30 records per page. So, when the user clicks on the next button, the next 30 records are displayed and so on.. I'm a newbie at Java so please kindly request you guys to help me out here. Any example would really be helpful.

Comment: You really mustn't like your users.  Why display all 500 rows and allow filtering?

Comment: How do I filter the data in `jtable` to show only 30 records per page?

Comment: Why limit it to 30 rows?

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have something like a nextPage and prevPage jButton?

Comment: No I don't have nextpage and prevpage buttons. That is what I need to know . How can I implement that in my program ?

Comment: And yes limit it to 30 rows because the size of my `jtable` would only show me 30 records. Hence I will need to move to the next page to show the next 30 rows. and so on..

Comment: I've had a 100, 000 rows in `JTable` before, I'm still scratching my head over why you want to limit to on 30 rows?

Comment: there are two ways paginations of DB side (better performance) or on the applications side (amount of data loaded from SQL can take some time, the same with 1st repaint on the screen)

Comment: I agree. I'm not limiting the number of rows, But the number of records that are visible to the user. I don't want the user to scroll down and up to see all the records. But instead implement  the concept of `pagination` which would have next and previous buttons to navigate the `JTable`.

Comment: by using google with the search text: "java jtable paging" i get on the top most result a working example. Analyse it? There are already some questions on SO. You give us no information what your exact problem is.

Comment: Yes I have seen that example. But i'm populating my `jtable` with the values in the database and not random values. How can I change that part of the code  ?

Comment: Andrew , how can you say it's a duplicate question ? I don't need to eliminate the scrollbars. I need buttons for pagination. And I did go through those posts, But there's no proper solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

well then have your complete list of data saved in your gui together with an index i refering to the current page. onClick of the mentioned buttons decreases/increases the index and updates the table data. the table data is the sublist of your complete data starting at (i-1)*30 and goes to Math.min(i*30-1,completeData.size())

Comment: An example would really help me here. I don't seem to understand what your saying. Sorry :(